# Cannot connect to MySQL when mysql computer is locked or idle

Tags: networking, windows-10, mysql

I have been experiencing an issue with mysql connection all of a sudden. 
I have three computers, mysql database installed on a computer A which is the server and other computers B & C which are the clients, the three computers are all in the same local network.

There is a similar question here, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18345743/mysql-connection-not-working-when-computer-is-locked but of different scenario.

The client computers has my application each which connects to the mysql database in Server A, but when server A goes idle (screen saver appears) or the computer is locked, then the application in the client computers can no longer connect to the mysql database in Server A until someone logs in to the Server computer A.

Pls what could be causing this and how can i resolve

Comment: it was installed as the Administrator user, or what s[ecifically do you mean and how do i check?

Answer (score 1):

Can you ping Server A when it goes idle? Maybe the the computer turns off network when it's idle.
If this is the case then do the following, (assuming server A is windows)

1. go to network connections (Win+R then type ncpa.cpl and enter)
2. right click on the network adapter, click Properties
3. click configure
4. go to Power Management tab
5. uncheck Allow computer to turn off device